# return formatted date from WebMethod to JSON

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json

I have a WebMethod that returns at date {"d":["/Date(1390411800000)/"]}:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static object getBreadCrumbDate(int projectID, int statusID)
    {
        using (dbPSREntities5 myEntities = new dbPSREntities5())
        {
            var thisId = myEntities.tbBreadCrumbs.Where(x => x.ProjectID == projectID && x.StatusID == statusID).Max(x => x.BreadCrumbID);
            var columns = myEntities.tbBreadCrumbs.Where(x => x.BreadCrumbID == thisId)
                                                  .Select(x => x.CreateDateTime).ToList();

            return columns;
        }
    }
```

and I want to format it "mmm dd, yy" (Jan 22, 14) and return it to the calling AJAX but not sure the best way. Here's my AJAX:

```
function getBreadCrumbDate(projectID, statusID) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "view-requests.aspx/getBreadCrumbDate",   // Current Page, Method
            data: JSON.stringify({
                projectID: projectID,
                statusID: statusID
            }), // parameter map as JSON
            type: "POST", // data has to be POSTed
            contentType: "application/json", // posting JSON content    
            dataType: "JSON",  // type of data is JSON (must be upper case!)
            timeout: 10000,    // AJAX timeout
            success: function (result) {
                $("#divApprovedStatus").html(result.d[0]);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                alert(status + " - " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

Right now it prints out /Date(1390411800000)/ but want it formatted. Is it best to do in the jQuery after the success or in the C# when I return it? Whichever way, I'm not sure how to do it and could use some pointers.
Thanks!

It shows some red lines... do you want me to tell you what they say?
[image]

Comment: CS1003: Syntax error, ':' expected
.Select(x => null != x.CreateDateTime ? x.CreateDateTime.Value.ToString("MMM d, yy")) : string.Empty) // this is just one example to handle null
Blue underline on ("MMM d, yy")) : string

Comment: extra ) at the end of "MMM d, yy")) - but now giving me:
"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method \u0027System.String ToString(System.String)\u0027 method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: But the error is returned in the AJAX call if that helps.

Comment: I fixed the extra parens. Checking the other. What version of Entity Framework are you running?

Comment: Again, thanks for taking the time to help. Version 4

Comment: ok code is working! I am getting AJAX error on NULL values. 
The cast to value type \u0027Int32\u0027 failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type\u0027s generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

Comment: This is a different column, not the DateTime, but an int. Are there nulls in your BreadCrumbID column in the data? This sounds like a separate issue?

Comment: I suggest if the formatting is working, which is the basis of your question, to start a new separate question for the NULLs if you need help there.

Comment: yep everything is working except NULLs. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say it's easiest to just do it in C# using `ToString([time format])` with the proper format.

Since you have a DateTime? object, known as a `Nullable<DateTime>`, to access the `DateTime` value, you have to use the `Value` property of `DateTime?` (The `Value` property exists on all `Nullable Types`.

For "Jan 22, 14", the format would be as follows:

These are just some generic examples of the syntax:

```
// DateTime object
someDateTimeInstance.ToString("MMM d, yy");

// DateTime? object
someNullableDateTimeInstance.Value.ToString("MMM d, yy"); // assumes no nulls

// DateTime? object with null check
String formattedDateTime = (null != someNullableDateTimeInstance 
    ? someNullableDateTimeInstance.Value.ToString("MMM d, yy")
    : string.Empty);
```

Additionally, you're using Entity Framework which translates your LINQ statements into SQL.

Basically you have to pull the data first, and then format it. Even though `CreateDateTime` IS a `Nullable<DateTime>` column, that entire expression is converted by Linq-To-Entities to SQL. And, Linq-To-Entities doesn't know how to translate the method call `.ToString(string format)`.

By separating the query from the format call, we avoid this issue. You get the data from the entities, and call `.ToList()` which will cause EF to load the data into memory. Then, you can work with this new list containing `DateTime?` objects and use the `ToString(string format)` method to get the formatted dates.

**In your code:**

```
[WebMethod]
public static object getBreadCrumbDate(int projectID, int statusID)
{
    using (dbPSREntities5 myEntities = new dbPSREntities5())
    {
        var thisId = myEntities.tbBreadCrumbs.Where(x => x.ProjectID == projectID && x.StatusID == statusID).Max(x => x.BreadCrumbID);
        var columns = myEntities.tbBreadCrumbs
            .Where(x => x.BreadCrumbID == thisId)
            .Select(x => x.CreateDateTime)
            .ToList();

        var formattedList = columns
            .Select(d => null != d
                ? d.Value.ToString("MMM d, yy")
                : string.Empty) // this is just one example to handle null
            .ToList();

        return formattedList;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the following but getting red underline that says "No overload method for 'ToString' takes 1 arguments.

Comment: .Select(x => x.CreateDateTime.ToString("MMM d, yy"))<--- red underline

Comment: It's coming from SQL Server and the column type is smalldatetime.

Comment: Would it have anything to do with CreateDateTime the column being the same name as the method CreateDateTime()? At a loss... it's definitely a DateTime but not sure why it's not working. Thanks for the help and let me know if you can think of anything else.

Comment: The debugger says DateTime? tbBreadCrumb.CreateDateTime
No Metadata documentation.

Comment: Sorry I probably sound dumb, but am I putting the top part somewhere in my code?
someDateTimeInstance.ToString("MMM d, yy");

someNullableDateTimeInstance.Value.ToString("MMM d, yy"); // assumes no nulls

etc...

Comment: No those are just examples. Just replace var columns line in your code with the code in my answer underneath "In your code". I added your whole code snippet with my update just in case.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help... I updated my question with an image of what I'm seeing.

Comment: @user1431633 I realized what was going on, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

if you can use datepicker then you could define a JavaScript function

```
  getDateFromJson: function(jsonDateString, languageCode) {
        return $.datepicker.formatDate($.datepicker.regional[languageCode].dateFormat, new Date(parseInt(jsonDateString.substr(6), 10)));
    }
```

and then you could define a i18n file for the datepicker as

```
jQuery(function ($) {
   $.datepicker.regional['en-us'] = {
       closeText: 'Done',
       prevText: 'Prev',
       nextText: 'Next',
       currentText: 'Today',
       monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
    'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
       monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
       dayNames: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
       dayNamesShort: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
    dayNamesMin: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
    weekHeader: 'Wk',
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
    firstDay: 1,
    isRTL: false,
    showMonthAfterYear: false,
    yearSuffix: ''
};
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['en-us']);
});

//German

   jQuery(function($){
$.datepicker.regional['de'] = {
    closeText: 'schließen',
    prevText: '&#x3c;zurück',
    nextText: 'Vor&#x3e;',
    currentText: 'heute',
    monthNames: ['Januar','Februar','März','April','Mai','Juni',
    'Juli','August','September','Oktober','November','Dezember'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Feb','Mär','Apr','Mai','Jun',
    'Jul','Aug','Sep','Okt','Nov','Dez'],
    dayNames: ['Sonntag','Montag','Dienstag','Mittwoch','Donnerstag','Freitag','Samstag'],
    dayNamesShort: ['So','Mo','Di','Mi','Do','Fr','Sa'],
    dayNamesMin: ['So','Mo','Di','Mi','Do','Fr','Sa'],
    weekHeader: 'KW',
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
    firstDay: 1,
    isRTL: false,
    showMonthAfterYear: false,
    yearSuffix: ''};
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['de']);
 });
```

So you could define your language and your dateFormat for it.

Now when you need a Date, just call this function

```
getDateFromJson(result.d[0], 'en-us'); //for USA Date
getDateFromJson(result.d[0], 'de'); //for German Date
```

Hope this points you in the right direction!